# Transform JSON object

Tags: javascript

I get such an object with rest api and I would like to convert it to something like:

Get object:

```
{  
   "base":"PLN",
   "rates":{  
      "USD":0.2645340686,
      "EUR":0.2336666978
   },
   "date":"2019-04-12"
}
```

I need to transform to:

```
[
    {
        "currency": "USD",
        "currency_exchange_rate": 0.264534068,
        "date_currency_exchange_rate_sync": "2019-04-12"
    },
    {
        "currency": "EUR",
        "currency_exchange_rate": 0.2336666978,
        "date_currency_exchange_rate_sync": "2019-04-12"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple. You can user `Object.keys` and `map` to create this transformation.

```
Object.keys(obj.rates).map(rate => {
    return {
        "currency":rate,
        "currency_exchange_rate":obj.rates[rate],
        "date_currency_exchange_rate_sync":obj.date
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map the entries of `rate` and take the date as well.

```js
var object = { base:"PLN", rates: { USD: 0.2645340686, EUR: 0.2336666978 }, date: "2019-04-12" },
    array = Object
        .entries(object.rates)
        .map(([currency, currency_exchange_rate]) => ({
            currency,
            currency_exchange_rate,
            date_currency_exchange_rate_sync: object.date
        }));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you object.entires on rates to get key/value pair and than map

```js
let obj = {  
   "base":"PLN",
   "rates":{  
      "USD":0.2645340686,
      "EUR":0.2336666978
   },
   "date":"2019-04-12"
}

let op = Object.entries(obj.rates).map(([currency,rate])=> ({
        currency,
        "currency_exchange_rate": rate,
        "date_currency_exchange_rate_sync": obj.date
}))

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer using JSONata expressions:

```
$each($.rates, function($v, $k){
    {
        "currency": $k,
        "currency_exchange_rate": $v,
        "date_currency_exchange_rate_sync": $.date
    }
})
```